# Transform this Clojure call into a lazy sequence

Tags: clojure, sequence, lazy-evaluation

I'm working with a messaging toolkit (it happens to be [Spread](http://www.spread.org) but I don't know that the details matter). Receiving messages from this toolkit requires some boilerplate:

1. Create a connection to the daemon.
2. Join a group.
3. Receive one or more messages.
4. Leave the group.
5. Disconnect from the daemon.

Following some idioms that I've seen used [elsewhere](http://github.com/acrosa/scala-redis), I was able to cook up some working functions using Spread's Java API and Clojure's interop forms:

```
(defn connect-to-daemon
  "Open a connection"
  [daemon-spec]
  (let [connection (SpreadConnection.)
        {:keys [host port user]} daemon-spec]
    (doto connection
      (.connect (InetAddress/getByName host) port user false false))))

(defn join-group
  "Join a group on a connection"
  [cxn group-name]
  (doto (SpreadGroup.)
    (.join cxn group-name)))

(defn with-daemon*
  "Execute a function with a connection to the specified daemon"
  [daemon-spec func]
  (let [daemon (merge *spread-daemon* daemon-spec)
        cxn (connect-to-daemon daemon-spec)]
    (try
     (binding [*spread-daemon* (assoc daemon :connection cxn)]
       (func))
     (finally
      (.disconnect cxn)))))

(defn with-group*
  "Execute a function while joined to a group"
  [group-name func]
  (let [cxn (:connection *spread-daemon*)
        grp (join-group cxn group-name)]
    (try
     (binding [*spread-group* grp]
       (func))
     (finally
      (.leave grp)))))

(defn receive-message
  "Receive a single message. If none are available, this will block indefinitely."
  []
  (let [cxn (:connection *spread-daemon*)]
    (.receive cxn)))
```

(Basically the same idiom as `with-open`, just that the `SpreadConnection` class uses `disconnect` instead of `close`. Grr.  Also, I left out some macros that aren't relevant to the structural question here.)

This works well enough.  I can call receive-message from inside of a structure like:

```
(with-daemon {:host "localhost" :port 4803}
  (with-group "aGroup"
    (... looping ...
      (let [msg (receive-message)] 
        ...))))
```

It occurs to me that `receive-message` would be cleaner to use if it were an infinite lazy sequence that produces messages. So, if I wanted to join a group and get messages, the calling code should look something like:

```
(def message-seq (messages-from {:host "localhost" :port 4803} "aGroup"))
(take 5 message-seq)
```

I've seen plenty of examples of lazy sequences without cleanup, that's not too hard.  The catch is steps #4 and 5 from above: leaving the group and disconnecting from the daemon.  How can I bind the state of the connection and group into the sequence *and* run the necessary cleanup code when the sequence is no longer needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://infolace.blogspot.com/2009/08/simple-webhooks-with-clojure-and-ring.html) article describes how to do exactly that using clojure-contrib fill-queue. Regarding cleanup - the neat thing about fill-queue is that you can supply a blocking function that cleans itself up if there is an error or some condition reached. You can also hold a reference to the resource to control it externally. The sequence will just terminate. So depending on your semantic requirement you'll have to choose the strategy that fits.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:use clojure.contrib.seq-utils))

(defn messages-from [daemon-spec group-name]
  (let [cnx (connect-to-deamon daemon-spec))
        group (connect-to-group cnx group-name)]
    (fill-queue (fn [fill]
                  (if done? 
                      (do
                        (.leave group)
                        (.disconnect cnx)
                        (throw (RuntimeException. "Finished messages"))
                      (fill (.receive cnx))))))
```

Set done? to true when you want to terminate the list.  Also, any exceptions thrown in (.receive cnx) will also terminate the list.